# SwiftUI: How to create a gradient with a lighter shade?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a gradient with 2 colors: the first color is a variable, and the other is the first color but X% brighter.

I tried doing the following, but apparently that isn't an acceptable color:

```html
linearGradient(colors: [someColor, someColor.lighten(amount: 0.1)], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
```

My alternative plan is to break down `someColor` into rgb components then calculate a lighter version of the color, but I can't figure out how to get the rgb components of a color..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you make do with using opacity to get the effect?

```swift
LinearGradient(
    colors: [someColor, someColor.opacity(0.5)],
    startPoint: .top,
    endPoint: .bottom
)
```

It depends on the background of course, to make it lighter you would ideally want white as background. Then again, if the background is the default system background then this approach would automatically give you a darker color with dark mode, which would be an advantage.

If it should always be lighter, then you could just apply a white background to the shape being filled. For example:

```swift
        Circle()
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(
                    colors: [someColor, someColor.opacity(0.5)],
                    startPoint: .top,
                    endPoint: .bottom
                )
            )
            .background {
                Color.white
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
```

Comment: I just tried applying opacity, and while I like the dark mode option, I'd rather have a lighter shade gradient. I'm not sure how applying a white background helps me achieve this, if you could give me a hint that'd be great!